# Include file into class that contains functions that are named identically

Tags: php, wordpress, mybb

I'm trying to build a class to bridge mybb and Wordpress.

When I include the mybb functions into Wordpress there are a couple that share the same name and so this creates PHP errors.

Is there any way I can include the mybb source but just pass variables to the main script without Wordpress throwing errors.. Essentially I need a function that includes the mybb source and also allows me to pass variables to it but keeps the included file isolated so as not to cause the conflicts with Wordpress functions that share the same name.

I am a PHP dev and I'm relatively familiar with how OOP works but far from an expert, il understand whatever solutions anyone has though. I've built the class but I'm stuck with the function names issue

Answer (score 0):

Two exactly the same function-names in the same class are indeed not valid in PHP. However, since PHP5 you can use namespaces. Hence, you can have the same class-name, with the same function-names, but with a different namespace (base).

What you can do is create a namespace for the mybb-class and a namespace for the Wordpress-class. Looking something like:

```
----
#file1.php full name is \mybb\ClassX
namespace \mybb;

class ClassX
{
  .. implementation ..

  public function SameName($a, $b)
  {
  }
}

----
#file2.php full name is \wordpress\ClassX
namespace \wordpress;
use \mybb\ClassX;

class ClassX
{
  .. implementation ..

  public $mybbClass;

  public function ClassX()
  {
    $mybbClass = new \mybb\ClassX();
    $mybbClass->FunctionWithSameName(1, 2);
  }
  public function FunctionWithSameName($a, $b)
  {
  }
}
```

See this link for full reference about usage of namespaces:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php